# Changing lables on x-axis like from Monday to show M as per window size in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts library to draw chart and I need to display Weekdays as labels on x-axis and also to auto reset it like from Monday to M if all weekdays can't fit on screen.

It should be dynamic, which means no flickering should appear when changing label text on x-axis.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight option for that, rather simple workaround:

1. Disable reflow from Highcharts, use `window.resize` browser event
2. In that event add condition to decide showing full name of just shortened, and set this for chart - `chart.xAxis[0].dateTimeLabelFormats` should be fine
3. After setting new format, apply new chart dimensions using `chart.setSize(w, h)`